# How to enable implicit casts in PostgreSQL >=9.2?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, pgadmin, cast

Coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856176/doctrine2-symfony2-cast-values-before-bind-to-dql-query/) topic on SO a user suggest me to enable implicit casts in my PostgreSQL and I don't know how to do that. I also don't know if this is a good practice or if it's the solution to the issues I'm having but I want to try this one since others solutions isn't working. So find information on Google I found this:

> For enable implicit casts you must therefore execute the following
>   commands in your PostgreSQL console when connected to the `template1`
>   database, so that any database created afterward will come with the
>   required CASTs (if your database is already created, execute the
>   commands in your database as well):

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_catalog.text(integer) RETURNS text STRICT IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE SQL AS 'SELECT textin(int4out($1));';
CREATE CAST (integer AS text) WITH FUNCTION pg_catalog.text(integer) AS IMPLICIT;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION pg_catalog.text(integer) IS 'convert integer to text';

CREATE FUNCTION pg_catalog.text(bigint) RETURNS text STRICT IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE SQL AS 'SELECT textin(int8out($1));';
CREATE CAST (bigint AS text) WITH FUNCTION pg_catalog.text(bigint) AS IMPLICIT;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION pg_catalog.text(bigint) IS 'convert bigint to text';
```

So my questions around this:

1. How do I execute that on `template1`? Any example will be helpful since I'm not a DBA just a simple developer and most of the time my tool & friend is pgAdmin or any other GUI on Windows
2. Can this be done easily from pgAdmin or any other GUI for Postgres or I need to work from command line?
3. Is this a good practice? Will be any performance issues afterwards?
4. Are this the only one queries I need to run to get ride of my problem?

Comment: It's not generally a good idea as it can have possibly confusing side-effects elsewhere in the database system, affecting things like choice of overloaded functions, and it can cause some incorrect queries to silently succeed. Implicit casts to text were removed for a reason. There'll be no performance impact.

Comment: @CraigRinger I think this is more or less the full answer one can give here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can also just add ?compatible=7.1 to a jdbc connection url (before the 42 release)... people say 'Implicit casts to text were removed for a reason' but in 10 years I have never had an issue with them. (I have fixed other bugs is pgsql though)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html

```
\dC
********* QUERY **********
SELECT pg_catalog.format_type(castsource, NULL) AS "Source type",
       pg_catalog.format_type(casttarget, NULL) AS "Target type",
       CASE WHEN castfunc = 0 THEN '(binary coercible)'
            ELSE p.proname
       END as "Function",
       CASE WHEN c.castcontext = 'e' THEN 'no'
            WHEN c.castcontext = 'a' THEN 'in assignment'
            ELSE 'yes'
       END as "Implicit?"FROM pg_catalog.pg_cast c LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc p
     ON c.castfunc = p.oid
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type ts
     ON c.castsource = ts.oid
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ns
     ON ns.oid = ts.typnamespace
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type tt
     ON c.casttarget = tt.oid
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nt
     ON nt.oid = tt.typnamespace
WHERE ( (true  AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(ts.oid)
) OR (true  AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(tt.oid)
) )
ORDER BY 1, 2;
**************************
                                         List of casts
         Source type         |         Target type         |      Function      |   Implicit?   
-----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+---------------
 abstime                     | date                        | date               | in assignment
 abstime                     | integer                     | (binary coercible) | no
 abstime                     | timestamp without time zone | timestamp          | yes
...
```